# Are general questions about how to use specific DAWs on topic?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope

For an example of a question I was thinking of, I wanted to know how I could use the pencil tool in the midi editor of Studio One to change the pitch of notes. This isn't really related to sound design directly, but I feel it's a little too niche to ask over on superuser. [This question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24062/how-can-i-map-midi-controller-faders-to-midi-cc-values-through-software-in-cubas), which I asked on AVP and got migrated here, is similar, but since it was part of a big migration I'm not sure if it's *really* on topic.

Would this type of question about how to accomplish *task* with *specific digital audio workstation* be kosher for this site?

Answer (score 3):

As it was on topic on AVP for the audio side and the audio side of AVP merged here, I believe it is on topic here.  That said, the SSD portion of the community is not very receptive to a lot of what the AVP community was and seem like they would rather see it crushed or forced back out to something seperate to keep it going.  Until such time as that separation is deemed neccesary though, I believe questions about DAWs would be on-topic.

Comment: Well I think we ARE understanding of what the AVP was, it was all that SSD wasn't basically. And those two different sites for some reason just had to be merged... And no we don't want what AVP was to be crushed. I think we all should be let back to what made both sections work, now when it's joined it just not gelling well.

Comment: +1 to what ErikG is saying. The bulk of us from SSD are trying to use this platform to learn more from one another and all this clutter from questions about DAWs would certainly benefit from happier responses from places like the SoundonSound forums for the various DAWs.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Learning to use basic daw tools is not at all sound design.

How to do it should be kosher IF the question was asked not from a usability standpoint but from a conceptual standpoint.

As in "I built the sequence up like THIS to accomplish THAT (type of feeling or creative solution), but I don't quite get it to work this way in ProTools. Any suggestions on how to do this differently?"

That is indeed a question in search of a specific technical/how-to answer. But based on a conceptual approach and seeking guidance on what to do next.

Comment: I like this answer. I agree the expectation is that the basics are just that - basic - but what is of real value is the stuff you can't find on a pro-tools manual page.

Comment: I agree. We are not a DUC or gearslutz or creativecow. Even before we came onto stack exchange, we would refer all these DAW related questions back to the respective DAW communities.

Answer (score -3):

i'll go first: no they are not, unless you want the RTFMs and down-votes.

Answer (score -5):

Gotta agree with georgi here. Definitely not on topic. This sort of thing should be on a studio one forum. I assume that exists somewhere on the interwebz.